# Promise fetching data

Tags: javascript, promise

I want to get certain data from this site https://swapi.co/.
I use Promises to get data about planets, then films within a certain planet object. Afterwards, I need to get data in the species array within the films array. Everything works up to this point.

My code for fetching info:

```
const task = planetId => {
  const url = `https://swapi.co/api/planets/${planetId}/`;
  const getPlanet = () => { // getting the planet by its Id
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
      https
        .get(`${url}`, function(res) {
          res.on("data", function(d) {
            const planetData = JSON.parse(d.toString());
            resolve(planetData);
          });
        })
        .on("error", function(e) {
          reject(e);
          console.error(e);
        });
    });
  };
  getPlanet().then(gotPlanet => {
    const planet = gotPlanet;
    const filmsArray = planet.films;
    const filmsArrayUrl = filmsArray.map(it => {
      return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) { // getting films array
        https
          .get(it, function(res) {
            res.on("data", function(d) {
              const films = JSON.parse(d.toString());
              resolve(films);
            });
          })
          .on("error", function(e) {
            reject(e);
            console.error(e);
          });
      });
    });
    Promise.all(filmsArrayUrl).then(gotFilms => {
      const filmsNew = gotFilms;
      planet.films = filmsNew;
      const speciesArray = planet.films.map(it => it.species);
      const speciesArrayUrl = speciesArray.map(it => it.map(el => { // trying to get the species data
        return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
          https.get(el, function(res) {
            res.on('data', function(d) {
              const speciesFetched = JSON.parse(d.toString())
              resolve(speciesFetched)
            })
          }).on('error', function(e) {
            reject(e)
            console.error(e)
          })
        })
      }))
      Promise.all(speciesArrayUrl).then(species => {console.log(species)})
    });
  });
};
```

The last line results in the console as `[Array[5], Array[20], Array[9]]` with each element inside the array as `Promise {<pending>}`.
What should I change in the code to get all species object and return the final result - a planet with fetched data on films and species within the films?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is very hard to follow, i suggest breaking out the reusable parts into their own promise such as the getDataObject piece below. You can then reuse that promise anytime you need to make an HTTP request.

```js
const getDataObject = url => fetch(url).then(res => res.json());

const task = planetId => {
    const planetUrl = `https://swapi.co/api/planets/${planetId}/`;
    let planet

    return getDataObject(planetUrl)
        .then(planetResponse => {
            //get the planet response
            planet = planetResponse

            //map through each film in the planet and get its film
            let filmsArrayUrls = planet.films.map(filmUrl => getDataObject(filmUrl));

            return Promise.all(filmsArrayUrls)
        })
        .then(allFilms => {
            //update the planet with the response for each film
            planet.films = allFilms;

            //map through all the species in the films
            let speciesArray = planet.films.map(film => film.species);

            //map through the species elements using Promise.All
            let speciesArrayUrl = speciesArray.map(species => Promise.all(species.map(el => getDataObject(el))))

            //Promise.All is itself a Promise, so you still need to resolve the Array of Promise.All objects inside of the speciesArrayUrl
            return Promise.all(speciesArrayUrl)
      })
      .then(species => {
        //return the species and do something with them
        for (let i = 0; i < species.length; i ++) { 
            planet.films[i].species = species[i] 
        }
        console.log(planet)
        return planet
      })
  };
  
task(2)
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I'd just change this line `planet.species = species` 
for `for (let i = 0; i < species.length; i ++) {
      planet.films[i].species = species[i]
    }`
Now it works just as I wanted it to.

Comment: Thanks, i updated the code with your suggested edit

Answer (score 0):

It's because `speciesArrayUrl` contains an array of an array of promises. You need to flatten out the array first.

One of the things you can do to flatten it out is to apply a *reducer* on `speciesArray` by appending `.reduce((items, item) => items.concat(item), [])`.

I rewrote your example using `fetch` so that it could run in the browser:

```js
const task = planetId => {
  const url = `https://swapi.co/api/planets/${planetId}/`;
  const getPlanet = () => { // getting the planet by its Id
    return fetch(url).then(res => res.json());
  };
  getPlanet().then(gotPlanet => {
    const planet = gotPlanet;
    const filmsArray = planet.films;
    const filmsArrayUrl = filmsArray.map(it => {
      return fetch(it).then(res => res.json());
    });
    Promise.all(filmsArrayUrl).then(gotFilms => {
      const filmsNew = gotFilms;
      planet.films = filmsNew;
      const speciesArray = planet.films.map(it => it.species)
        .reduce((items, item) => items.concat(item), []);
      const speciesArrayUrl = speciesArray.map(it => { // trying to get the species data
        return fetch(it).then(res => res.json());
      })
      Promise.all(speciesArrayUrl).then(species => {console.log(species)})
    });
  });
};

task(2);
```

I also took a stab at refactoring the code to make it more readable:

```js
function getPlanet(planetId) {
  return fetch(`https://swapi.co/api/planets/${planetId}/`)
    .then(res => res.json());
}

function getFilms(planet) {
  return Promise.all(planet.films.map(f => fetch(f).then(res => res.json())));
}

function getSpecies(film) {
  return Promise.all(film.species.map(s => fetch(s).then(res => res.json())));
}

getPlanet(2)
  .then(planet => getFilms(planet))
  .then(films => Promise.all(films.map(film => getSpecies(film))))
  .then(filmSpecies => [].concat(...filmSpecies)) // flatten array of films and film species
  .then(species => {
    console.log(species);
  });
```